# Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending

Tags: contract-development

```
Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
Returned error: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":"execution reverted","errorData":"0x118cdaa700000000000000000000000064c20ee5b4476bc4eb5dd236498669335382cd31","id":6521087768983387}
```

---

**Contract code**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Pausable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Burnable.sol";

contract ElanaArt is ERC721, ERC721Enumerable, ERC721URIStorage, ERC721Pausable, Ownable, ERC721Burnable {
    constructor(address initialOwner)
        ERC721("Unique", "LIFE")
        Ownable(initialOwner)
    {}

    function pause() public onlyOwner {
        _pause();
    }

    function unpause() public onlyOwner {
        _unpause();
    }

    function safeMint(address to, uint256 tokenId, string memory uri)
        public
        onlyOwner
    {
        _safeMint(to, tokenId);
        _setTokenURI(tokenId, uri);
    }

    // The following functions are overrides required by Solidity.

    function _update(address to, uint256 tokenId, address auth)
        internal
        override(ERC721, ERC721Enumerable, ERC721Pausable)
        returns (address)
    {
        return super._update(to, tokenId, auth);
    }

    function _increaseBalance(address account, uint128 value)
        internal
        override(ERC721, ERC721Enumerable)
    {
        super._increaseBalance(account, value);
    }

    function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId)
        public
        view
        override(ERC721, ERC721URIStorage)
        returns (string memory)
    {
        return super.tokenURI(tokenId);
    }

    function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId)
        public
        view
        override(ERC721, ERC721Enumerable, ERC721URIStorage)
        returns (bool)
    {
        return super.supportsInterface(interfaceId);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Please add more details, when are you facing this error?

Answer (score 0):

```
 This error facing when i click on transact while i try to mint my NFT
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### this is the Debug

[block:18383438 txIndex:60]from: 0x64c...2cd31to: UniqueFish.safeMint(address,uint256,string) 0xDC4...AAa59value: 0 weidata: 0xcd2...00000logs: 0hash: 0xb91...09653
transact to UniqueFish.safeMint pending ...
transact to UniqueFish.safeMint errored: Error occured: execution reverted.

execution reverted
The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Error provided by the contract:
OwnableUnauthorizedAccount
Parameters:
{
"account": {
"value": "0x64c20eE5b4476bC4eB5dD236498669335382cd31"
}
}
Debug the transaction to get more information.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

iam already have deployed contract but i dont click on proxy before i doplying is there is any update i can do after i have deploying contract ?

Comment: Please add all the informations on the question post (by clicking "Edit") instead of writing multiple answers.

Answer (score 0):

iam already have deployed contract but i dont click on proxy before i doplying is there is any update i can do after i have deploying contract ?

[image]